# Can not find class define, when I build a Spring Boot application with Maven by Jenkins and execute JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, classpath

- I suppose it can not find the class path. Because I can run the jar file JAR in a local environment of the IDE ([IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)). I use the code snippets below to print class path information.

  `ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
  URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
  if (urls == null || urls.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("Is this a empty classpath?");
  }
  for(URL url: urls){
      System.out.println("This is classpath:" + url.getFile());
  }`

When I click the <kbd>Run</kbd> button in IntelliJ IDEA, it can list all dependency class, such as, It's right.

> This is classpath:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar
>      This is classpath:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar

But when I run it locally, it just prints one message. It's just my JAR package directory. It's wrong.

- I read [the documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) about the manifest file. It does contain a JAR file. Its location is main/resources directory. But it has no directory prefix. It's generated by IntelliJ IDEA automatically. And I unzip the JAR package to check the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. It also contains the Main-Class key.

  > Manifest-Version: 1.0
  >   Class-Path: spring-data-rest-core-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar mapstruct-1.1.0.F
  >    inal.jar logback-core-1.1.11.jar javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
- I check my pom.xml file. It has the maven-jar-plugin configuration. I comment out classpathPrefix and classpathLayoutType. I consider it seems like no use.

  `<plugin>
    <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
          <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->
              <mainClass>com.hzlf.LetFunGoApplication</mainClass>
              <!--<classpathPrefix>/Users/admin/.m2/repository</classpathPrefix>-->
              <!--<classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>-->
          </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>`

  I doubt it is a wrong configuration for this maven-jar-plugin. Its classPathPrefix is a relative path. How can I write it correctly about repository? My local Maven home directory is `/Users/admin/.m2/`. In my Docker container, it's `/root/.m2`.
- I use a Jenkinsfile to pull an image from Docker hub in my project. Here is my
  Jenkinsfile configuration. In the `deliver.sh` file, just to run the JAR package.

  `pipeline {
      agent {
          docker {
              image 'maven:3-alpine'
              args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
          }
      }
      stages {
          stage('build') {
              steps {
                  sh 'mvn --version'
                  sh 'mvn clean package'
              }
          }
          stage('Test') {
              steps {
                  sh 'mvn test'
              }
              post {
                  always {
                      junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                  }
              }
          }
          stage('Deliver') {
              steps {
                  sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
              }
          }
      }
  }`

  This is error information. It confused me a long time.

  > Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
  >   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpMessageConverters
  >       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  >       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  >       at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  >       at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  >       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  >       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
  >       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
  >   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters
  >       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  >       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  >       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  >       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  >       ... 7 more
  >   [Pipeline] }
  >   [Pipeline] // stage
  >   [Pipeline] }
  >   $ docker stop --time=1 693b10dd721c5780761b00eef880b793f6fa2e94afb77e9ffbac9474360f8a5f
  >   $ docker rm -f 693b10dd721c5780761b00eef880b793f6fa2e94afb77e9ffbac9474360f8a5f
  >   [Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
  >   [Pipeline] }
  >   [Pipeline] // withEnv
  >   [Pipeline] }
  >   [Pipeline] // node
  >   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
  >   ERROR: script returned exit code 1
  >   Finished: FAILURE

  [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaMnb.png
    [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbVvJ.png

Comment: If you are using spring boot there is a plugin spring-boot-maven-plugin which handles all the stuff to create an executable jar file...There is no need to define maven-jar-plugin etc... just use the spring-boot-maven-plugin...Further details in the spring boot docs...

Comment: I have used spring-boot-maven-plugin in my pom.xml and set 'fork' key into 'true' value.

Comment: Why are you doing that? What is the problem? Please stay with defaults if you don't have a very good reason...

Comment: resolve it. it's my fault. The config of jenkins file is wrong. It should delete 'post' item.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by modifying my deliver.sh. I don't know the real reason, but it works. I just delete Test stage and Deliver stage. I guess it results from the 'post' option in deliver.sh.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```